Pick random element of comma-separated string list in LibreOffice Calc
I have a list of strings in LibreOffice Calc which are comma separated and gathered through the TEXTJOIN(...) function. The output is e.g.: ABCD, EFGH, IJKL, MNOP, QRST, UVWX, YZAB. Now, I want to have function that grabs a random 4-character string out of this list, e.g. IJKL and place it into a different cell.
Background: The string list is mutable and may change by time. It's used to create a school invigilator's overview. How can I achieve this?
Thanks a lot in advance.
